# Qbs: Rule for install step

Tags: qbs

In short: is it possible to make `Rule` item (or similar) to be executed at `install` step?

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115652/qbs-install-files-preserving-hierarchy), I have issues with installing files via `Group` item. A simple `Rule` script will probably do, but it has to be run at some point, preferably during installation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your primary question is answered in the question you linked to.

Rules cannot be run at install time. They can however produce files which are installed via the file tags assigned by rules.

For example:

```
Group {
    fileTagsFilter: ["someruleoutput"]
    qbs.install: true
    qbs.installDir: "xyz"
}
```

This will cause any files with the tag "someruleoutput" generated by rules in your product or its dependent modules, to be installed to the "xyz" directory.